# Magento filter product collection by tier price for current customer group

Tags: php, collections, magento, filter, callback

How do I filter a product collection by looking at whether a tier price for the current customer group has been set?

I think I need to look at the `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` table to see if there is an entry for the `current customer_group_id` for each product in the collection (if there isn't, the product should be excluded / filtered from the collection), but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

Background: Some products are not available to certain customer groups, and we are using tier price to make that determination (i.e. if a tier price exits, include in collection and display, if not, exclude and don't display).

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yup, this should be achievable, but try not to think about it in terms of tables, but rather as objects and collections.

The Product object has a method `getTierPrice` which uses a Factory pattern to return tier pricing depending on the product type (Simple, Bundle, etc).  That method checks the current visitor's group when calculating the tier prices.

So, tier price is not an attribute in the classic Magento sense which means that you can't filter by attribute, instead you could use the `walk` function on the collection to calculate the Tier Price, and then filter the collection by the updated values.

An example of a walk function might be:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->walk('Namespace_Module_Helper_Data::removeStockData',array());
```

then within your `Namespace_Module_Helper_Data`, you have something like:

```
public static function removeStockData($product = null)
{
    $product->setData('stock_item',null);
    return;
}
```

Alternatively, you could run the collection through a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($collection->getItems() as $key => $item){
   if($item->getTierPrice($qty) == $item->getPrice()){  //insert your own criteria
        $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While I understand what you are saying in theory, I have not been successful in putting it into practice. Co you have any links to actual code samples that may help me understand how to do this?

Comment: yup, I'll post an example shortly

Comment: thanks for the sample code. I still have questions. 1) is it possible to remove items from the collection using the `walk()` function? If so, how? 2) when I use `getSize()` before and after your `foreach` example to iterate through the collection (removing all items with a key of < 100), I get the same result. What am I missing?